# PHP shift array order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Im working on something and i need to shift an array with ID's so the ID(person) cant get his own ID unless the "game" is over.

So i got this:

```
$array = array(
    "2"  => "2",
    "3"  => "3",
    "6"  => "6",
    "8"  => "8",
    "12" => "12",
);
```

And i want it this way:

```
 $array = array(
        "2"  => "3",
        "3"  => "6",
        "6"  => "8",
        "8"  => "12",
        "12" => "2",
    );
```

I'm not a real php hero and the internet isn't helping so far :)

Thx in advance!

Comment: You want array key to be array value.? Like `"2" => "2"`, `"x" => "x"` .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after long trying and getting some help from an old friend this is the final result:

```
    $prev = null;
    $firstIndex = null;
    foreach ($userArr as $i => $user) {
        if (is_null($prev)) {
            $firstIndex = $i;
            $prev = $user;
            continue;
        }
        $userArr[$i] = $prev;
        $prev = $user;
    }
    $userArr[$firstIndex] = $prev;
```

Comment: That's not what you asked for!  No pleasing some people ;)

Comment: That's exactly what i asked for, but thx for your lovely comment!

Comment: Your function takes keys and values of 2,3,6,8,12 and results in the same keys being mapped to 12,2,3,6,8.  Which isn't exactly what you asked for.  But glad you found something that worked for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$in = array(
    "2"  => "2",
    "3"  => "3",
    "6"  => "6",
    "8"  => "8",
    "12" => "12",
);

$out = array(
    "2"  => "3",
    "3"  => "6",
    "6"  => "8",
    "8"  => "12",
    "12" => "2",
);

function transpose_values(array $in) {
    $values = array_values($in);
    $first  = array_shift($values);
    $first && array_push($values, $first);
    $out = array_combine($in, $values);

    return $out;
}

assert($out == transpose_values($in));
```

Comment: Very nice, avoid assuming use of PHP7 though :-)

Comment: @theruss, this isn't Php7 dependent is it?

Comment: you've used scalar type-hinting in your `transpose_values` function which is a PHP7 only feature.

Comment: Php 5 introduced basic type hinting (not scalar types).

Comment: Sorry can't user PHP  7, can you help me with an other option? Thx in advance :)

Comment: Above tested and working under Php 5.45.  Ignore @theruss's comment.

Comment: Sorry @Progrock, I am an idiot; Scalars are...well, scalars. And not arrays. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the array's values are supposed to represent, it's a little heard to tell what you're actually trying to do. The way it looks is that a person's (user's?) ID will represent something entirely different given some particular scenario.

Taking your question at face-value therefore, you need a new array, with the values of the old one to be those values, one-position ahead of where they were originally. Use of reset() and next() are the keys here:

```
$newArray = [];
$firstVal = reset($array);

$i=0;
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    ++$i;
    // Deal with the last array-element to be given the first's value
    if(count($newArray) === $i) {
        $newArray[$key] = $firstVal;
    } else {
        $newArray[$key] = next($array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor description. This is what im trying to build:
I'm making a game called [Gotcha] (https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_(spel)) could not find the EN version, online! Every player gets a target which he needs to "kill". If the player kills his target he gets the target of his just killed target. The game goes on till everyone is dead or the player gets his own target card.
So if you don't want to change the target cards in game you have to make a forced loop as a described above. But i'm struggling to get the values shifted, also as above described.
:)